# Applicability of using Back-Propagation Neural Network given continuous class labels

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I am given a dataset where the class labels are continuous values between `[-1,1]`. Based on this, I have few questions:

1. Can I use Back-Propagation Neural Network (BPNN) for this problem? Previously, I had a different dataset where the labels are **binary classes** but for this dataset I am not sure since it is now a regression problem.
2. In case neural network can work with this dataset, what activation function should I use? `Sigmoid`, hyperbolic tan function (`tanh`), or rectified linear unit (`relu`)?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean class labels are in this range? Are they supposed to be independent of each other?